# How to use value inserted into SQLite column in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I would like  to use values inserted into SQLite but I don't know how to do that.

I have create  "favoriteItems" table with id.

```
`create table if not exists favoriteItems(id integer primary key not null);`
```

And then, I have inserted several IDs into this table.

```
`insert into favoriteItems (id) values (${value.id});`
```

Above codes all are working now.

However, I don't know how to import these IDs and to use in my function.

```
 db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
      `select id from favoriteItems where id is not null;`,
      null,
      // I don't know way to import ids from SQLite and use these,
    );
  });
```

Could someone help me, please.

Comment: you want to pull values from db to react native?

Comment: Yes, I do. Can I pull value like string or num style from db?

Comment: yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a success callback to `executeSql`, which takes two params `transaction` and `resultSet`.

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql(
    `select id from favoriteItems where id is not null;`,
    null,
    (tx, result) => {
      // save your results in state here
      // this.setState({
      //   data: result.rows._array
      // });
      console.log(result)
    },
    (tx, error) => {
      // error logic here
      console.log(error)
    }
  );
});
```

`tx.executeSql` takes four parameters

```
tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, arguments, success, error)
```

*s**qlStatement*** (string) sql statement

***arguments*** (array) An array of values (numbers or strings) to substitute for ? placeholders in the SQL statement.

***error*** (fn) called when there's an error with **(tx, error)**

***success*** (fn) called on success with **(tx, resultSet)**

resultSet contains the following

```
{
  insertId,
  rowsAffected,
  rows: {
    length,
    item(),
    _array,
  },
}
```

[resultSet Object](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#resultset-objects)

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/sqlite-example)